# My Kentia Palm has crunchy and black leaves

Tags: houseplants, leaves, indoors, palm, kentia

My Kentia Palm has crunchy and black leaves. I have checked the roots and they look fine. I then applied neem oil but this didn't seem to stop the spreading of the plant. The base of the plant looks OK. I do see tiny red spots but they don't seem to move and seem to be native to the plant?

The plant is located 2m from a window where it gets a max of 2 hours direct sunlight if ever.

The soil feels OK, not too moist at least. It's still in it's nursery pot from when I first bought it 6 months ago.

It started with the lowest leaves but now the upper once have also been infected.

Is this some kind of fungus?

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]